# Как я могу запустить бот телеграмм (go lang), скомпилированный в бинарный файл на сервере через прокси?

Tags: golang

Как это может быть сделано? Есть бинарный файл. Я просто загружаю его на сервер (Ubuntu), потому что я не знаю, как правильно развернуть бота на сервере ... затем я запускаю его (./app), сначала устанавливаю права доступа к файлу, после запуска естественно, пишет, что он не может подключиться к телеграмме API, может кто-нибудь сказать мне, как развернуть бота в Ubuntu или unix системах, чтобы он мог подсоединиться к апи
 телеграма?

Я использую эту библиотеку для бота https://github.com/go-telegram-bot-api/telegram-bot-api/wiki

Не нашел, есть ли способ подключения через socks в нем, у кого есть опыт, поделитесь, будет полезно) Конечно было бы здорово как то разворачивать сокс на том же сервере куда и устанавливается бот, За любую помощь буду благодарен.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Посмотрел бот, там есть публичный клиент для соединения. В нем можно поменять транспорт, который будет идти через прокси
Делается примерно так:

```
bot.Client.Transport = &http.Transport{
    Proxy: http.ProxyURL(proxyURL),
}
```

Или можно задать транспорт по умолчанию для всей программы, где он не меняется:

```
http.DefaultTransport.Proxy = http.ProxyURL(proxyURL)
```

Но это не очень хороший метод

proxyURL можно сделать так:

```
proxyStr := "http://localhost:7000"
proxyURL, err := url.Parse(proxyStr)
if err != nil {
    log.Println(err)
}
```

localhost:7000 заменить на свой прокси

Comment: спасибо за помощь